# How to check if checkbox is checked in view page with razor and if checked display a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

How can I check if a checkbox is checked in view page with razor and if checked display a textbox!

I'm new in asp.net mvc and razor, still learning.

**View Code**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SupportRequired)    
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AssistName new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Very simple: `@if (Model.SupportRequired) { /* textbox here /* }` - probably need to break it into multiple lines because the Razor parser might not like it otherwise.

Comment: My code had a syntax error. I edited it. Please see it again.

Comment: When page is loading.. check the value of `SupportRequired` property and show and hide the textbox..

    `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AssistName new { @class = "form-control", style="display:@(Model.SupportRequired == true ? "block": "none")})`

Comment: Just curious, is this for an Edit page?  If so, you would like this to happen on load?  Please be more clear.  What happens if the checkbox is checked on load of the page then the user unchecks it?  This can be done via JS/jQuery, or if it is as simple as showing the textbox onload of the page, then just Razor will suffice

Answer (score 6):

You can use JavaScript like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SupportRequired , new { id = "MyChk", onchange = "valueChanged()"})  
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AssistName , new { id = "MyTxt" , @class = "form-control" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged() {
        if ($('#Mychk').is(":checked"))
            $("#MyTxt").show();
        else
            $("#MyTxt").hide();
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**

For show or hide in page load you need add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    valueChanged();
});
```

Comment: @PeterB thx for comment, I added double quote, But where is the comma left?

Comment: For future reference (not saying your code is wrong in anyway), you don't need to give the `CheckBoxFor` and `TextBoxFor` custom `id` attributes.  If you would've left it just like the OP posted, you could've just used `$("#SupportRequired")` and `$("#AssistName")`.  Razor does this dynamically for you

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to set the textbox to hide on page load as the txt box is displayed on page load.

Comment: How do you hide the label @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SupportRequired, new { style = "display: none", "What support do you require:" })

Comment: @Tom It can be done like TextBoxFor, set id and show or hide by JavaScript.